# How can I make an Optional 1:1 Relationship in EF6 with the same Entity Type on both sides?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want my Donut to optionally relate to another Donut, and if so, the other donut would relate back.  From what I've read, I believe I need to set this up as a Parent/Child relationship, even though in the real world, it's just an optional pairing (Donuts can exist by themselves happily, or exist in pairs).  Here is my current setup:

```
public class Donut {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentDonutId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildDonutId { get; set; }

    // virtual properties
    public virtual Donut ParentDonut { get; set; }
    public virtual Donut ChildDonut { get; set; }
}
```

This statement in my mapping file gets me close, but insists on creating a new key named `ParentDonut_Id` on the table instead of using my existing `ParentDonutId`:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ChildDonut)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.ParentDonut);
```

But when I try this mapping:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ChildDonut)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.ParentDonut)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentDonutId")); // or "ChildDonutId"
```

I get this error message when trying to `Add-Migration`:

`ParentDonutId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'ParentDonutId' is already defined.`

How should I set up this relationship?  Is it possible?  It seems logical enough to me, but maybe it's one of these things DB's don't let you do?

EDIT: I came across this hack, which will probably allow me to do what I need, but it doesn't allow navigating backwards from a child to a parent Donut, which would be nice to have:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.ChildDonut)
            .WithMany() // haxx
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ChildDonutId);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to create an one to one relationship? For example, one donut could not be parent of two (or more) different donuts?

Comment: Correct, in my use case, they only come in pairs or singly..  Otherwise a `.WithMany(ChildDonuts)` would probably be best..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you map both sides? I think this should work:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Donut>()
        .HasOptional(e => e.ChildDonut)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.ChildDonutId);

 modelBuilder.Entity<Donut>()
        .HasOptional(e => e.ParentDonut)
        .WithMany()
        .WithMany(t => t.ParentDonutId);
```

To understand more about self-referencing take a look at this thread [Second Self-To-Self relationship in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943984/second-self-to-self-relationship-in-entity-framework)